# What is the difference between "gull" and "seagull"?

Tags: nouns, word-difference, comparison

I'm Spanish and we have the word `gaviota` to describe the marine bird. Searching for the translation I have found that can be translated as `gull` and `seagull`. Is there any difference in the meaning between both?

Comment: A gull is bigger then a seagul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in this context, no.

"Gull" can be used as a verb, where it means to trick someone. But the nouns are synonyms.

Comment: *Gull* is also used as a noun for the victim of the fraud.

Comment: I don't think I've ever heard/seen that usage @StoneyB.

Answer (score 4):

My dictionary tells me that [seagull](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/seagull) is "a popular name for a gull".

Some distant knowledge tells me that the proper term is gull, but I practically exclusively use "seagull" to refer to this bird (and any that look remotely similar)

Comment: Yes, gull is the proper name but practically everyone calls them seagulls.